# How to modify the output file to get my desired formatting

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to generate a Python code for getting output in a text file following a particular format. The format I want is: If in the subsequent lines, the order of entries are same to a certain point, then delete all the entries upto that point (leaving the last one) and generate a final text file. In the following sections I will describe what am I trying to do and what I am getting.
[Data File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLUKG.png)
[Python Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuK2E.png)

```
outputfile = open('webgrapviz.txt', 'w')
for data in all_data:
    line=""
    for k,item in enumerate(data):
        if len(item)==0: continue
        if len(line)==0:
              line=line+'"'+item+'"'
        else:
              line=line+"-> "+'"'+item+'"'

    line = line + "\n"
    outputfile.write(line)
outputfile.close()
```

The output I am getting is:

```
"Subsea Production"-> "Subsea Landing String Services"-> "SenTURIAN E&A Well Test Subsea Landing String Electrohydraulic Operating System"
"Subsea Production"-> "Subsea Landing String Services"-> "SenTURIAN Large-Bore Subsea Landing String Electrohydraulic Operating System"
"Subsea Production"-> "InterventionConstrained & Subsea Applications"-> "MaxFORTE High-Reliability ESP System"
"Subsea Production"-> "Intervention-Constrained & Subsea Applications"-> "ZEiTECS Shuttle Rigless ESPReplacement System"
"Subsea Production"-> "OneSubsea, a Schlumberger company"
```

The output I want is:

```
"Subsea Production"-> "Subsea Landing String Services"-> "SenTURIAN E&A Well Test Subsea Landing String Electrohydraulic Operating System"
"Subsea Landing String Services"-> "SenTURIAN Large-Bore Subsea Landing String Electrohydraulic Operating System"
"Subsea Production"-> "InterventionConstrained & Subsea Applications"-> "MaxFORTE High-Reliability ESP System"
"Intervention-Constrained & Subsea Applications"-> "ZEiTECS Shuttle Rigless ESPReplacement System"
"Subsea Production"-> "OneSubsea, a Schlumberger company"
```

Comment: Could you give us the file that you are reading. And also what is `all_data`, it is not defined in the code you posted.

Comment: Hi @palvarez I have added the code, and the data as well as images with the post. Please see them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is this, maybe there is a better way to do it in terms of performance.

```
outputfile = open('webgrapviz.txt', 'w')
prev_data = []
for data in all_data:
  data = [x for x in data if x] # Filter empty strings
  if not data:
    continue
  # Compare with previous data and get the index where they differ
  index = 1
  if prev_data:
    for index, (first, second) in enumerate(zip(data, prev_data)):
      if first != second:
          break
  prev_data = data
  data = data[index-1:]                    # Remove repeated items
  data = map(lambda x: '"%s"' % x, data)   # Add double quotes
  line = "-> ".join(data) + "\n"           # Generate line with join
  outputfile.write(line)
outputfile.close()
```

Output file:

```
"Subsea Production"-> "Subsea Landing String Services"-> "SenTURIAN E&A Well Test Subsea Landing String Electrohydraulic Operating System"
"Subsea Landing String Services"-> "SenTURIAN Large-Bore Subsea Landing String Electrohydraulic Operating System"
"Subsea Production"-> "Intervention-Constrained & Subsea Applications"-> "MaxFORTE High-Reliability ESP System"
"Intervention-Constrained & Subsea Applications"-> "ZEiTECS Shuttle Rigless ESPReplacement System"
"Subsea Production"-> "OneSubsea, a Schlumberger company"
```